# PHP overload "=" operator

Tags: php, operator-overloading

Is there a way to overload the equals operator?

Let's say I have this code:

```
$variable1 = "a";
$variable1 = "c";
```

I would like to save to a log file everytime i assign something to `$variable1` without having to do something like:

```
$variable1 = "a";
add_to_some_logfile("a");

$variable1 = "c";
add_to_some_logfile("c");
```

Is there a way to override the equals operator in order to do some other operation other than just assigning the value to the variable?

Comment: Why'd this get voted down? It's a legit question

Comment: You can't overload it on variables, but you can kind of overload it for class properties using the `__set()` magic method.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: @G-Nugget how can i use it with session variables?

Comment: @Harlandraka You could write a class wrapper that, but you can't do it directly with `$_SESSION`;